# Query optimization PHP for string concatination

Tags: php, mysql

I have an entity `RegistrationForm` which has a OneToMany-relationship with  `SurveyAnswer`.

An answer can either have a collection of `FormOptions` (when the answer is of type `MULTIPLE_CHOICE`) or a `content` represented by a string (type `TEXT-FIELD`, `TEXTAREA` etc.).

Below is a function inside the `RegistrationForm`-entity that tries to obtain a string-based representation of the answer's content.

```
public function getAnswerByColumnId($columnId) {
    foreach ($this->surveyAnswers as $answer) {
        if ($answer->getFormQuestion()->getId() == $columnId) {
            $formOptions = $answer->getFormOptions();
            if (count($formOptions) > 0) {
                $content = '';
                foreach ($formOptions as $key => $option) {
                    if ($key == 0) {
                        $content .= $option->getName();
                    } else {
                        $content .= ' , ' . $option->getName();
                    }
                }
                return $content;
            } else {
                return $answer->getContent();
            }
        }
    }
    return 'No column match, contact admin';
}
```

I am creating a table out of the registration forms. Each registration form has a few answers that are of a multiple-choice type.

The result is that the `foreach ($formOptions as $key => $option) {...`-section is pumping the amount of queries up from **200 to 2500**.  How can I improve this?

Answer (score 3):

For now, one solution is to concatenate the options into a string while the answer is persisted. This is part of my `FormToArrayTransformer`:

```
switch ($_question->getFormField()->getType()) {
    case FormField::CHOICE:
        $content = '';

        foreach($answer as $_key=>$option) {
            $surveyAnswer->addFormOption($option);
            if ($_key == 0) {
                $content .= $option->getName();
            } else {
                $content .= ', ' . $option->getName();
            }
        }

        $surveyAnswer->setContent($content);
        break;
```

Note that now both the `FormOption` entities and their string representation is stored. When viewing you don't have to iterate over the options anymore but simply calling `answer.getContent()` will do. This saved me 2300 queries in a table for 200 forms.

I am still unsure why this is so.